# Polynomial bound

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, inequality

Let $P(x)=a_4 x^4+a_3 x^3+a_2 x^2+a_1 x+a_0$ such that
$$\forall i\in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\};\phantom{;}a_i\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge |a_i|\leq T\phantom{.}(T\in\mathbb{Z}^+ )$$
Suppose that $P(x)> 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R};\phantom{;}P(x)\ge \frac{1}{2^{195} T^{64}}$$

Comment: Source? ${}{}{}$

Comment: False: $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 0.$

Comment: This is not easy. The general case is treated here: http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~perrucci/On_the_minimum_simplex.pdf

Comment: ivan// Thanks !!